# Lua scripting for repeating mouse movements

Tags: lua, mouseevent, logitech-gaming-software

I am trying to write a script and I am brand new to Lua and scripting as well.  This will be used to click and drag (moving an item), return, click and drag again.  Then press left mouse button and hold (5 seconds).  Then rest for 1.5 seconds.  I would like this to repeat using the G1 Key(or another key if G keys don't work well) as a toggle on a logitech keyboard using GHub.  I am getting a script error and I don't know if this is easily fixable.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1  then
        if script_running then
            script_running = false
            return
        else
            script_running = true
        end
            MoveMouseTo(130, 250)
            PressMouseButton(1)
        repeat
            MoveMouseTo(800, 850)
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
           MoveMouseTo (200, 250)
           PressMouseButton(1)
       repeat
           MoveMouseTo (800, 850)
           ReleaseMouseButton(1)
           PressMouseButton(1)
           Sleep(5000)
           ReleaseMouseButton(1)
           Sleep (1500)
        until not script_running
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, open GHub and assign action "Back" to physical key G1 on your Logitech keyboard.
("Back" is the default action for mouse button #4, so G1 will duplicate its functionality, I assume the game is ignoring mouse button #4)

```
-- Set your screen resolution here
local screen_width = 1920
local screen_height = 1080


local active, exit

local function SleepG1(ms)
   local tm = GetRunningTime() + ms
   repeat
      Sleep(10)
      local G1 = IsMouseButtonPressed(4) -- 4 = "Back"
      active, exit = G1, exit or G1 and not active
   until GetRunningTime() > tm
end

local function MoveMouseToPixels(x, y)
   -- x, y from 0,0 to 1919,1079
   x = math.max(0, math.min(screen_width  - 1, math.floor(x * 65535 / (screen_width  - 1) + 0.5)))
   y = math.max(0, math.min(screen_height - 1, math.floor(y * 65535 / (screen_height - 1) + 0.5)))
   MoveMouseTo(x, y)
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      active = not active
      if active then
         exit = false
         Sleep(10)

         repeat
            -- click and drag (moving an item)
            MoveMouseToPixels(130, 250)  -- in pixels
            SleepG1(50)
            PressMouseButton(1)
            SleepG1(50)
            MoveMouseToPixels(800, 850)  -- in pixels
            SleepG1(50)
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
            SleepG1(50)
            -- click and drag again
            MoveMouseToPixels(200, 250)  -- in pixels
            SleepG1(50)
            PressMouseButton(1)
            SleepG1(50)
            MoveMouseToPixels(800, 850)  -- in pixels
            SleepG1(50)
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
            SleepG1(50)
            -- press left mouse button and hold (5 seconds)
            PressMouseButton(1)
            SleepG1(5000)
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
            SleepG1(50)
            -- rest for 1.5 seconds.
            SleepG1(1500)
         until exit

         active = true
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: I am sure that I overlooked something.  So far I can't make the script work.  I have assigned the back function to my G1 key on the Logitech Keyboard.  In game, I press the G1 key with no function yet noted.   I also meant to add a momentary press of the Tab button before moving the mouse the first time.   This will also repeat.

Comment: What are the numbers (130, 250, etc)?  Are they coordinates in pixels?